# Bluetooth HID device

Tags: usb, linux, keyboards, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth keyboard which I would like to use on my laptop.
My laptop runs Linux and I have had it working in the past but it wasn't stable.

I'm now looking for a bluetooth adapter which will connect to my keyboard over bluetooth and acts as a standard HID device on the USB port of my Linux laptop. Because it presents itself as a standard HID device, it should work in the BIOS and any OS with USB support.

If you have another (creative) solution that might do the job I would love to hear that as well.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are looking for a bluetooth dongle that also has another USB port build in, right?

Comment: No (sorry for the confusion), The device I'm looking for connects over bluetooth to my keyboard and connects over USB to my laptop. The USB connection on my Linux machine needs to see a HID device instead of a bluetooth adapter.

Comment: You're looking for a Bluetooth dongle that presents itself to the computer as a USB HID device?  I'm not sure such a thing can exist: I don't think USB HID provides any way for such a device to pair itself with a keyboard.

Comment: I need this. I have an Apple Bluetooth keyboard I really, really like typing on, but it's impossible to use it to navigate the bios, and syncing link keys between OS's is an absolute PITA. I always have to get my old USB keyboard out of the closet!